# Can not find record in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following problem: I am receiving a GET variable in a url. If the variable GET arrives, I send the contents of the variable to my controller.

My controller first brings the whole "sales" table, then I look for the record that has the same content of the GET variable in a column. Finally, I update the status of that record I found.

But nothing happens, and I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

I leave the code:

**PHP file where the variable GET is received:**

```
if(isset( $_GET['number'])){

$number = $_GET['number'];

$response = CartController::ctrShowSales($number);

echo $response;

}
```

**PHP Controller:**

```
static public function ctrShowSales($number){

    $table = "sales";

    $respuesta = CartModel::mdlShowSales($table);

    $find = 0;

    foreach ($response as $key => $value) {

        if ($value["number"] == $number) {

            $find = 1;
            $id = $value["id"];

            break;

        } 

    }

    if ($find == 1){

        $response2 = CartModel ::mdlUpdateRecord($table, $id);
        return $response2;

    } else { return "Did not find";}

}
```

**PHP Model:**

```
static public function mdlShowSales($table){

    $stmt = Conection::conect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");

    $stmt -> execute();

    return $stmt -> fetch();

    $stmt -> close();

    $tmt =null;

}

static public function mdlUpdateRecord($table, $id) {

    $stmt = Conection::conect()->prepare("UPDATE $table SET status = :status WHERE $id = :$id");

            $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":status", "Verified", PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($stmt -> execute()){

        return "ok";

    }else{

        return "error"; 

    }

    $stmt -> close();

    $stmt = null;

}
```

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: Use the database to find the record. Not php. Also, this issue is probably that the function `mdlShowSales` doesn't return all record. Try fetchAll.

Comment: You're loading the entire table into memory to find a single record. This could bring down your server if you have a large number of records. Instead do a focused query `WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1` and get the specific row you need.

Comment: You're returning before closing the table. That's probably not a good idea, (though PHP might do this for you automatically, but still).

Comment: Also, this part `$id = :$id` is problematic. You probably mean `$id = :id` instead

Comment: There's also `UPDATE $tabla` instead of `UPDATE $table`. MySQL should squawk at you though, telling you these things, so maybe that's not it.

Comment: @Chipster:  I think `$id` is the value in the column, not the column name.  We see it referenced in the `bindParam`.  I think the SQL was meant to `id = :id` ... but that's just a guess.

Comment: @spencer7593 that was my thought too.

Comment: `WHERE $id = :$id` - is a syntax error 100%,  consider `$id=1`  `WHERE 1 = :1`  In fact without that `:` they would have a big issue.... `UPDATE ... WHERE 1=1`  in other words your one colon away from wrecking your table, because `$id` is always equal to `$id` which would basically update every row in your DB!

Comment: `$tabla` as in `UPDATE $tabla SET` is a point just waiting for SQL Injection, even if you prepare this query, if a user can choose that value, your sunk.  You can use a white list of table names to check that against.  But that should be done right when the query is being done, so that nothing can 'sneak' in. also  `UPDATE $tabla SET status = :status WHERE number = :number LIMIT 1` - I think is basically what you are doing.

Comment: `foreach ($response as $key => $value) {`  see `$respuesta = CartModel::mdlShowSales($table);`  ~ `$response` is undefined AS is `return $respuesta2;` etc...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I have already corrected the publication's writing errors. I'm looking at each of your answers and analyzing

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix What I try to do in the update of the sale, is to modify the value of the state in the record that has as id the id found in the foreach. That's why I do a WHERE $ id =: id. Or am I wrong and to do that I have to do it differently? Consider that my understanding of PHP is basic and that is why I may have syntax errors

Comment: @JohnJ. The `$` in a string treats treats the next space delimited text a variable, and thus replaces its value accordingly. Thus, `"$id=:$id` replaces each of these ids with $is's value. So if `$id=1`, it would look like `1=:1` which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other answers I would add this simple method to your models,

```
protected static $tables  = ['sales'];

final static public function ckTable($table){
     if(false !== ($index = array_search($table, static::$tables, true))){
         return $tables[$index]; //return your table value
     }
     throw new Exception('Unknown Table');
}

static public function mdlShowSales($table){
       //here you can clearly see the table is being handled
       $safeTable = self::ckTable($table); //use a different var here


       $stmt = Conection::conect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $safeTable");
       ....

      //or $stmt = Conection::conect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".self::ckTable($table));
}
```

Right now you have only the fact that you hard coded this, in your controller:

```
$table = "sales";
```

All it would take is to one day make this mistake in a controller

```
//here you cannot tell if this is safe to do or not as you cannot see how the query is done.
static public function somepage($table){
      $respuesta = CartModel::mdlShowSales($table);
}
```

And you would be open to SQL Injection even if you prepare the query.

Right now it's just Improbable that, that will happen, we should make this impossible.

Also, this is basically what you are doing:

```
//everything under PHP Controller can be done with this sql:
SELECT id FROM sales WHERE number = :number LIMIT 1
/*
  SELECT * FROM sales
foreach ($response as $key => $value) {   
        if ($value["number"] == $number) { //-- WHERE number = :number
            $find = 1;
            $id = $value["id"]; //-- SELECT id
            break; //-- LIMIT 1
        } 
    }
 */

//mdlUpdateRecord
UPDATE sales SET status = :status WHERE id = :id
```

So why not just do this

```
UPDATE sales SET status = :status WHERE number = :number LIMIT 1
```

Basically I am just rewording your code into just SQL, you can do it however you want.  I think maybe ordering will be an issue here with Limit 1 if your order is different and you have multiple `number` rows for the same value.  But I don't know what your DB looks like to say for sure, this is true with your original code as well.

Answer (score 0):

change in your model to fetch results associative:

```
static public function mdlShowSales($table){

    $stmt = Conection::conect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");

    $stmt -> execute();

    return $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $stmt -> close();

    $tmt =null;

}
```

and then your controller:

```
static public function ctrShowSales($number){

    $table = "sales";

    $respuesta = CartModel::mdlShowSales($table);



    foreach ($response as $value) {

        if ($value["number"] == $number) {

           $response2 = CartModel ::mdlUpdateRecord($tabla, $id);
    return $respuesta2;

        } 

    }

     return "Did not find";

}
```